can't upgrade macOS version on Macbook air 2015 from Catalina to any newer version
I have a MacBook Air 2015 and I'd updated it to Catalina when it released. now I'm trying to upgrade it to macOS 12. but when I go to software update it says there's no update. and when I use link to App Store from any newer version than 10.5 after I click get it says update not found on software update window which opens


Try https://support.apple.com/en-ca/102662

Just curious, are you running a high-resolution external monitor? Because screenshot quality looks retina-ish to me (while MacBook Air 2015 didn't have a retina screen)

I actually copied the page from somewhere else. But the content where exact same.

You will want to download a copy of Monterey (macOS 12) and use it to create a bootable USB, which you can use to update the MBA.
Refer to Apple's instructions on how to create the bootable USB.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/101578

Thanks for the answer! I'll test it
